# modal popup extender problem

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

i use modal popup extender to show my details in another separate window it is a panel contains some controls the problem is ::
when i click on my button which contains::
the Show() method the parent page just frozen and no popup appears at all on the other side i have a grid view when  i click on the last button on it the popup appears where the other buttons on the grid view make the same behavior of my first button , i donot know what is the problem my panel visibility = true and no setting in my behind code..i view the source and i find the panel with its contents then why the popup window doesnot appear..i search alot but i donot find a solution to my problem ..
my aspx::

```
<asp:Panel id="master_editMode"  runat="server"  >                    
                 <div id="masterDiv" style="width:98%"  dir="rtl">
                    <div id="masterControls"  align="center">
                    <table border="0" width="98%">


                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" dir="rtl">
                                <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjDS_AllTasks" runat="server" 
                                    SelectMethod="Get_All_Tasks" TypeName="DocumentFlowModuleDTO.TaskDTO">
                                </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hd_Task_Code" runat="server" />
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text="Search for Task" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Search" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                                                ontextchanged="txt_Search_TextChanged" Width="200px" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            &nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="3">


                                            <asp:GridView ID="grd_AllTasks" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                                                AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="Alternating" DataKeyNames="task_code" 
                                                DataSourceID="ObjDS_AllTasks" 
                                                onpageindexchanging="grd_AllTasks_PageIndexChanging" 
                                                onrowdatabound="grd_AllTasks_RowDataBound" style="margin-right: 0px">
                                                <RowStyle VerticalAlign="Top" />

                                                    HeaderText="ÍÐÝ">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_Delete_Task" runat="server" 
                                                                CommandArgument="<%# Bind('task_code') %>" Height="33px" 
                                                                ImageUrl="~/Images/delete.png" oncommand="btn_Delete_Task_Command" 
                                                                Width="67px" />
                                                            <cc1:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="btn_Delete_Task_ConfirmButtonExtender" 
                                                                runat="server" ConfirmText="åá ÊÑíÏ ÍÐÝ æËíÞÉ ÇáÇÚÊãÇÏ ¿" Enabled="True" 
                                                                TargetControlID="btn_Delete_Task">
                                                            </cc1:ConfirmButtonExtender>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                </Columns>
                                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                            </asp:GridView>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" dir="rtl">
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_TaskName" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="13pt"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" dir="rtl" style="height: 196px">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_No_States" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_AddStatesToTask" runat="server" 
                                                ImageUrl="Images/add.png" onclick="btn_AddStatesToTask_Click" Visible="False" />

                                            <asp:Button ID="Dummy_btn2" runat="server" Text="Button" Style="display:none;" /> 
                                            <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="btn_AddStatesToTask_ModalPopupExtender" 
                                                runat="server" 
                                                TargetControlID="Dummy_btn2"
                                                BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" 
                                                PopupControlID="pnl_Add_States"
                                                DropShadow="True">
                                            </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hd_StateSerial" runat="server" />
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hd_StateRowIndex" runat="server" />
                                <asp:GridView ID="grd_States" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" DataKeyNames="state_serial" 
                                    onpageindexchanging="grd_States_PageIndexChanging" Visible="False" 
                                    CssClass="Alternating" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="state_name" HeaderText="ÇáãÑÍáÉ" 
                                            ShowHeader="False" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="state_order" HeaderText="ÊÑÊíÈ ÇáãÑÍáÉ" 
                                            ShowHeader="False" />
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Power" ShowHeader="False">
                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chb_StatePower" runat="server" 
                                                    Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("power_flag")) %>' Enabled="False" />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <ItemStyle Width="40px" />
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="New" ShowHeader="False">
                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" />


                                                <asp:Button ID="Dummy_btn4" runat="server" Text="Button" Style="display:none;" />

                                                            <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="btn_TaskState_Edit_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server"
                                                            TargetControlID="Dummy_btn4"
                                                            BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" 
                                                            PopupControlID="pnl_Add_States"
                                                            DropShadow="True">
                                                            </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>

                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ÍÐÝ" ShowHeader="False">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_TaskState_Delete" runat="server" 
                                                    CommandArgument="<%# Bind('state_serial') %>" Height="26px" 
                                                    ImageUrl="~/Images/delete.png" oncommand="btn_TaskState_Delete_Command" 
                                                    Width="47px" />
                                                <cc1:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="btn_TaskState_Delete_ConfirmButtonExtender" 
                                                    runat="server" ConfirmText="åá ÊÑíÏ ÍÐÝ ÇáãÑÍáÉ ¿" Enabled="True" 
                                                    TargetControlID="btn_TaskState_Delete">
                                                </cc1:ConfirmButtonExtender>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource_States" runat="server" 
                                    SelectMethod="Select_TaskStates" TypeName="DocumentFlowModule.DTO.TaskStateDTO">
                                    <SelectParameters>
                                        <asp:Parameter Name="task_code" Type="Int32" />
                                    </SelectParameters>
                                </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>


        <asp:Panel ID="pnl_Add_Task" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup"><%-- Style="display:none;"--%>
          <div id="div3" style="width: 95%">
                <div id="div4" align="center">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpPnl1" runat="server">
                                <ContentTemplate> 
                                    <table dir="rtl" style="text-align: right">
                                        <tr bgcolor="#f1ece2">
                                            <th align="right" height="35" valign="middle" colspan="3">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_New_Task" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="14pt" 
                                                    Text="ÅÖÇÝÉ æËíÞÉ ÇÚÊãÇÏ" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Edit_Task" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="14pt" 
                                                    Text="ÊÚÏíá æËíÞÉ ÇÚÊãÇÏ" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="title" width="160">

                                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Task Name"></asp:Label>

                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width: 140px">

                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_TaskName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                                            </td>
                                            <td>

                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                                                    ControlToValidate="txt_TaskName" ErrorMessage="*" ValidationGroup="G1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="title" width="160">

                                                <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="DataBase Name"></asp:Label>

                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width: 140px">


                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_DataBases" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                                                    ondatabound="ddl_DataBases_DataBound" 
                                                    onselectedindexchanged="ddl_DataBases_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                                </asp:DropDownList>


                                            </td>
                                            <td>


                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" 
                                                    ControlToValidate="ddl_DataBases" ErrorMessage="*" InitialValue="--Select--" 
                                                    ValidationGroup="G1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>


                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="title" width="160">

                                               <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Table Name"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width: 140px">
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Tables" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                                                            ondatabound="ddl_Tables_DataBound" 
                                                            onselectedindexchanged="ddl_Tables_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                                        </asp:DropDownList>

                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" 
                                                            ControlToValidate="ddl_Tables" ErrorMessage="*" InitialValue="--Select--" 
                                                            ValidationGroup="G1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                                                    <td class="title" width="160">

                                                                        <asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" Text="Table Key"></asp:Label>

                                                                    </td>

                                                                    <td style="width: 140px">
                                                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_Key" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                                        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbl_Columns" runat="server">
                                                                        </asp:CheckBoxList>
                                                                    </td>

                                                                    <td>

                                                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_Select_Key" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>

                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                                                    <td class="title" width="160">

                                                                        <asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server" Text="Current Record State"></asp:Label>

                                                                    </td>

                                                                    <td style="width: 140px">
                                                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Columns" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                                                                            ondatabound="ddl_Columns_DataBound">
                                                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                                                    </td>

                                                                    <td>

                                                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" 
                                                                            ControlToValidate="ddl_Columns" ErrorMessage="*" InitialValue="--Select--" 
                                                                            ValidationGroup="G1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="title" width="160">
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Form View "></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width: 140px">
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_F_View" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" 
                                                    ControlToValidate="txt_F_View" ErrorMessage="*" InitialValue="--Select--" 
                                                    ValidationGroup="G1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="title" width="160">
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Form New"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>                                         

                          </table>
                 </ContentTemplate>

                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>                                   
                                <td dir="rtl" align="center">
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_OK" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/add.png" 
                                        onclick="btn_OK_Click" ValidationGroup="G1" Visible="False" />
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_Edit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/edit.png" 
                                        onclick="btn_Edit_Click" ValidationGroup="G1" Visible="False" />
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_Cancel_Task" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                        Height="36px" ImageUrl="~/Images/cancel.png" onclick="btn_Cancel_Task_Click" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
               </table>


                </div>

                </div>
        </asp:Panel>
```

the btn_add _task does not make my popup appear just freeze the parent page

---

my .cs

```
protected void btn_Add_Task_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender modal1 = (AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender) table1.FindControl("btn_Add_Task_ModalPopupExtender");
        //modal1.Show();

        grd_States.Visible = false;
        lbl_No_States.Text = "";
        btn_AddStatesToTask.Visible = false;
        lbl_TaskName.Text = "";

        //master_editMode.Visible = true;

        //pnl_Add_Task.Visible = true;

        btn_OK.Visible = true;
        btn_Edit.Visible = false;
        lbl_New_Task.Visible = true;
        lbl_Edit_Task.Visible = false;

        txt_TaskName.Text = "";
        ddl_DataBases.ClearSelection();
        ddl_Tables.Items.Clear();
        ddl_Columns.Items.Clear();
        cbl_Columns.Items.Clear();
        txt_F_New.Text = "";
        txt_F_View.Text = "";
        txt_Params.Text = "";
        txt_SP_Name.Text = "";

        btn_Add_Task_ModalPopupExtender.Show();

    }
```

thanks in advance

EDITED::

`<table align="center"  dir="rtl">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td >
                                                    <asp:Button ID="Dummy_btn" runat="server" Text="Button" Style="display:none;" />`

```
                                                <asp:Button ID="btn_Add_Task"  runat="server" Text="ÅÖÇÝÉ æËíÞÉ ÇÚÊãÇÏ ÌÏíÏÉ" 
                                                    onclick="btn_Add_Task_Click" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="12pt" 
                                                    ForeColor="#0066FF" />

                                                <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="btn_Add_Task_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" 
                                                    TargetControlID="Dummy_btn"
                                                    PopupControlID="pnl_Add_Task"
                                                    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
                                                    DropShadow="True" >

                                                </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>`
```

Comment: The `TargetControlID` property of your `ModalPopupExtender` might be the problem. Can you post your page markup?

Comment: I can't find a `ModalPopupExtender` named `btn_Add_Task_ModalPopupExtender` in your markup. Where is it defined?

Comment: sorry i edit my answer ,, my aspx is so long so i have to delete many lines in the middle of my aspx thant donot affect my question identity..

Answer (score 1):

If you want your modal popup to be displayed when the user clicks on the `btn_Add_Task` button, you should set that button as the `TargetControlID` of the extender:

```
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="btn_Add_Task_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" 
    TargetControlID="btn_Add_Task" PopupControlID="pnl_Add_Task"
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DropShadow="True" />
```

In your current code, the modal popup is triggered by a button named `Dummy_btn`, which I can't find in your markup, but which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: sorry it exist <<it is just a dummy button i use to allow execute my server side code in btn_Add_Task when i make  TargetControlID="btn_Add_Task" as usual the it just execute the client side code ,, i search through the net and i find this trick to overcome my problem

Comment: @user418343, do you mean a button click executes some of your code but doesn't show the popup?

Comment: yeah with my current code the state is: when click this button the parent page will be turned to be dimmed (frozen) as required ,when trace the code it pass with Show method and execute it but no pop up appear at all ,,when click on the last button on my gridview it works finely and appear the pop up i donot know what is the problem with my button ,,when viewing source i find the contents of the panel in the popup ,i tried to change the position but the position of my popup doesnot changed at all.

Comment: @user418343, are you sure you don't have code calling `btn_Add_Task_ModalPopupExtender.Hide()` later in the page cycle (for instance during the `PreRender` phase)?

Comment: just here:: ` protected void btn_Cancel_Task_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            btn_Add_Task_ModalPopupExtender.Hide();
           
        }
`

Comment: `Show()` renders a client script to display the modal popup when the page loads. Maybe that script can't execute. Do you have errors in your Javascript console after clicking on `btn_Add_Task`?

Answer (score 1):

We had many issues with ajax popup. you might want to try the approach we have been using for past one month or so with out any issues. This approach creates a popup with out need of ajax / jquery / javascript /css/ update panel .

here:
[A modal popup with out using ajax, update panel, jquery or javascript- surprisingly this seems to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25220746/a-modal-popup-with-out-using-ajax-update-panel-jquery-or-javascript-surprisin)